# Laravel's passport authentication works only with GET method

Tags: php, laravel, rest, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using ionic that consumes a REST API made in laravel with passport's authentication. My problem is that when I make GET requests it works perfectly but when I try to send data using the PUT method it always returns 'Unauthenticated'.

My put call to the API that not works

```
update(data) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token
    });
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.http.put(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/api/user`, {
            headers: headers,
            data: data
        }).subscribe((result:any)=>{
            resolve(result.json());
        },(error:any)=>{
            reject(error.json());
        });
    })
}
```

My GET CALL that works

```
getCurrentUser() {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token
    });
    return this.http.get(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/api/user`, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

On LARAVEL routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {

    Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::put('/user','UserController@update');

});
```

update method on controller

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $user = User::find($request->user()->id);


    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'nome'=> 'required|max:255',
        'cpf' => 'required|max:14',
        'telefoneCelular' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json(['message'=>$validator->errors()],400);
    }else{
        $user->nome = $request->input('nome');
        $user->cpf = $request->input('cpf');
        $user->telefoneCelular = $request->input('telefoneCelular');
        if($user->save()){
            return response()->json(['data'=>$user],201);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Erro ao atualizar usuário'],400);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: it works with POSTMAN

Comment: can i see update method?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth Off course, I've edited the post with the update method

Comment: ift it's work with postman it's not a problem with laravel it's with your js code, so do you test with chrome ?

Comment: Yes, I've only tested with chrome. I can't see anything wrong with my js code given that is almost the same code that I'm using to make my GET request.

Comment: go to inspect->network and do the put request again and in the network tab click on your request and check your request method, is it going as the PUT ?

Comment: Here is my request [link](https://pasteboard.co/He1xWgj.png) and here are the response [link](https://pasteboard.co/He1yhl8.png)

Comment: Does `this.token` contain `Bearer: <token>`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, it does and with the same content that I use in `` `getCurrentUser()`, `getCurrentUser()` works.

Comment: I don't see `Authorization: Bearer <token>` on any of your requests. the `GET` request you've shown is just a pre-flight OPTIONS check

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The previously images was missing one part of the request, [here](https://pasteboard.co/He1Hoxh.png) are the image with the full content of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the problem is that i was passing the wrong parameters to `this.http.put`

here is the code that works

```
update(data) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token
    });
    console.log(headers);
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.http.put(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/api/user`, data, {
            headers: headers,
        }).subscribe((result:any)=>{
            resolve(result.json());
        },(error:any)=>{
            reject(error.json());
        });
    })
}
```